# Relation between minimal and distal homeomorphism on compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I would like to compare **minimal** homeomorphisms and **distal** homeomorphisms on a **compact metric space**.

$f$ is said to be minimal if $\overline{Orb(x)}=X$ for all $x \in X$.

And $f$ is said to be distal if for $x \neq y$ then $\inf_{n \in \mathbb{z}} \{ d(f^n(x),f^n(y))   \} >0$.

It is easy to see that distal homeomorphism does not imply minimal homeomorphism.

For example: Identity map on an interval.

But, I have no idea about the converse?

Could you please help me find a counter example or proof for it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, any minimal and mixing system will suffice. A standard example (in continuous time) is the horocycle flow one constant negative curvature surface. I know there are also more recent discrete-time examples, but I am not familiar with them.